# How to post and get data - JSOUP JAVA

Tags: java, jsoup

Guys I am trying send post method to https://www.servientrega.com/wps/portal/Colombia/transacciones-personas/rastreo-envios and get results of tracke and trace. I need to send this number for example  : 2003159943. This is my code:

```
Connection.Response Form = Jsoup
       .connect("https://www.servientrega.com/wps/portal/Colombia/transacciones-personas/rastreo-envios")
        .validateTLSCertificates(false)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

        Document document = Jsoup
        .connect("https://www.servientrega.com/wps/portal/Colombia/transacciones-personas/rastreo-envios")
        .validateTLSCertificates(false)
        .data("txtNumGuia", "2003159943")
        .cookies(Form.cookies())
        .post();
```

I need to get this history: 
[Image with the data what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXOeC.png)

but I get this when I tried println(document):

[Image with the result what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAjFZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e7hy.png)

Comment: I've inspected the browser's traffic to the site and it looks that it send the number with a `get` request and not `post`.

Comment: I tried but not. I am same.

Comment: Thank you very much. I Searched in all document and I didn't see the link web.servientrega.com/PortalServientrega/WebServicePortal/tracking/api/envio... I can continue programming.! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you want to obtain are set by javascript after page is downloaded. Jsoup does not execute javascript, it only downloads initial html.

If you examine what connections are made, for example with browser debugging tools you will find out, that the data are downloaded with request to the api: https://web.servientrega.com/PortalServientrega/WebServicePortal/tracking/api/envio/2003159943/1/es

The data you are looking for should be in response.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://web.servientrega.com/PortalServientrega/WebServicePortal/tracking/api/envio/2003159943/1/es")
                         .validateTLSCertificates(false) 
                         .ignoreContentType(true) 
                         .get(); 
System.out.println(document.text());
```

Comment: Hey Luk, I belive You can help me with another thing. How Can I fill table with three columns (movimiento-ubicacion-fecha) with the result of: https://web.servientrega.com/PortalServientrega/WebServicePortal/tracking/api/envio/2003159943/1/es